# NetStandard 1.3 incompatible with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-standard

I have a thin NetStandard 1.3 library shared with Xamarin developers.
But cannot bring this NuGet package to Azure Functions because it complains about:

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported.

Here is a GitHub case with all the detail:
https://github.com/lindydonna/FunctionsAsWebProject/issues/6#issuecomment-299928757

Comment: Just looked at the GH issue. Can you confirm you're seeing this when running locally? What version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: Ues same problem running locally, CLI beta.94